# Why can't I store a state getter/setter in a global context?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-state

Can anyone tell me why this won't work?

- Page1 creates a state "num" (initialized to 0) with useState and stores the getter/setter in a context held in App
- Page2 accesses the num setter through context and sets num to 1
- Page3 accesses the num value through context and displays it

I expect Page3 to display num=1, but in fact it displays num=0. It seems that the setNum call on Page2 is not working as I expect it to.

Downloadable example [here](https://github.com/acewert/context-example):

App.js

```
import { SharedContext } from './context';

function App() {
  const [context, setContext] = useState(null);

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <SharedContext.Provider value={{ context, setContext }}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Page1 />} />
          <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
          <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
        </Routes>
      </SharedContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

Page1.js

```
export default function Page1() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { setContext } = useContext(SharedContext);
    const numState = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        setContext(numState);
    }, []);

    const onClick = () => {
        navigate('/page2');
    };

    return <button onClick={onClick}>Next</button>;
}
```

Page2.js

```
export default function Page2() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { context } = useContext(SharedContext);
    const [num, setNum] = context;

    const onClick = () => {
        setNum(1);
        navigate('/page3');
    };

    return <button onClick={onClick}>Next</button>;
}
```

Page3.js

```
export default function Page3() {
    const { context } = useContext(SharedContext);
    const [num, setNum] = context;

    return <div>num = {num}</div>;
}
```

Comment: Instead of a downloadable example, make a codesandbox

Comment: Im confused by your description. Are you saying that when you click "Next", it doesn't set `num` to `1`?

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev yes it does set `num` to 1, but the context ain't updated so the other pages don't receive that change. Page 1 will have `num=newestValue` while all other pages will forever be `num=0`

Comment: @AndrewEwert, Why are you building this so complicated? Why don't you lift `const [num, setNum] = useState(0);` up into `App`? Why this detour over `const [context, setContext] = useState(null)`?

Comment: @Thomas Because they're not using context correctly. They dont want to put their child state setter into the context.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev Sorry, you’re right. I should have done a codesandbox

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Looks like you're running into some trouble accessing the state in the context API. Just a friendly reminder that the state will only be defined once Page1.js is rendered. But don't worry! I've got a solution for you. Give this implementation a try and it should get the job done

**context.js**

```js
import { createContext, useState } from 'react';

export const SharedContext = createContext({
    num: null,
    setNum: () => {}
});

export const SharedContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(null);
    
    return <SharedContext.Provider value={{num, setNum}}>{children}</SharedContext.Provider>
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import { SharedContext, SharedContextProvider } from './context';

function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <SharedContextProvider>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Page1 />} />
          <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
          <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
        </Routes>
      </SharedContextProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

**Page1.js**

```js
export default function Page1() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { setNum } = useContext(SharedContext);

    useEffect(() => {
        setNum(0);
    }, []);

    const onClick = () => {
        navigate('/page2');
    };

    return <button onClick={onClick}>Next</button>;
}
```

**Page2.js**

```js
export default function Page2() {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { setNum } = useContext(SharedContext);

    const onClick = () => {
        setNum(1);
        navigate('/page3');
    };

    return <button onClick={onClick}>Next</button>;
}
```

**Page3.js**

```js
export default function Page3() {
    const { num, setNum } = useContext(SharedContext);

    return <div>num = {num}</div>;
}
```

Also, Just wanted to give you a friendly reminder that when using the React.JS Context API, make sure to declare default values for the properties you're using inside the createContext function. This will help avoid any potential issues when trying to access the state. Have a great day!

```js
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const SharedContext = createContext({
    context: null,
    setContext: () => {};
});
```

[Docs on createContext](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createContext)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! Unfortunately, when I do this, it still behaves as before. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't _have_ to provide meaningful default values. It can just be a `null`. Either way, default vlaues don't come into play here.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev. I understand. But if you don't pass any parameters, then it's `undefined.`

Comment: `value={{ context, setContext }}` passes the parameters

Comment: So is it the same as `createContext({context: null,setContext: () => {};})` ?

Comment: No because the default value is inherently stateless. It's only used if a Provider `value` isn't provided. Read the docs you linked.

Comment: @AndrewEwert, I see that you're having some trouble with the `num` state implementation. I've made some edits to the post with a fresh approach that I think will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The core issue is you are trying to set a state setter inside of a state setter on a global context. The much simpler way to do it is:

**context.js**

```js
import { createContext } from "react";

export const SharedContext = createContext();
```

**app.js**

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Page1 from "./Page1";
import Page2 from "./Page2";
import Page3 from "./Page3";
import { SharedContext } from "./context";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ num: 0 });

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <SharedContext.Provider value={{ state, setState }}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Page1 />} />
          <Route path="/page2" element={<Page2 />} />
          <Route path="/page3" element={<Page3 />} />
        </Routes>
      </SharedContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**Page1.js**

Notice the removal of the unnecessary `useState`.

```js
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Page1() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const onClick = () => {
    navigate("/page2");
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Next</button>;
}
```

**Page2.js**

Notice how we use one global state setter, and not a nested setter setter? You set the global state and destructure the previous state so you don't lose any other state variables that are not `num`.

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { SharedContext } from "./context";

export default function Page2() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const context = useContext(SharedContext);

  const onClick = () => {
    context.setState({
      ...context.state,
      num: 1,
    });
    navigate("/page3");
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}>Next</button>;
}
```

**Page3.js**

```js
import { useContext } from "react";
import { SharedContext } from "./context";

export default function Page3() {
  const context = useContext(SharedContext);

  return <div>num = {context?.state?.num}</div>;
}
```

BTW, using your code as-is in a sandbox, I see several errors thrown, because in several areas you are trying to **destructure** `{ setContext }` when the parent object is initially **undefined** - which is why Typescript users here are recommending you set the state values initially. It actually does matter.

Slava and other users made good points.

**Working Sandbox**

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/trusting-neco-svgp1z

I will provide a Typescript-version along with more proof as to why it's incredibly important to define a context initially, OR be prepared to handle for undefined in your code with `?` checks which is not ideal.

[image]

Comment: Page1 correctly sets it to `0`. It is Page2 that OP claims does not set it to `1`.

Comment: Better `useEffect(()=>{ ... }, numState);` without the surrounding array. The current version is equivalent to `useEffect(()=>{ ... })` since the numState array will be generated on every useState call even if the content is the same (over multiple rerenders)

Comment: Slava, sure but undefined initial state is problematic. TS helps prevent these issues.

Using his code in Sandbox, you'll see undefined errors on `context`, and the attempted destructure of `{ setContext }` because context is lazily undefined initially, which is a bad design paradigm.

Also, setting a state setter inside of a state setter inside of context is bad. Just use the single global state setter to set the state, while simply using destructure on the existing state object to handle existing nested values.

Thomas, you are correct that was a bad initial recommendation on my part.

Answer (score -2):

The way you access your context is incorrect, because you are mirroring the `useState` pattern while that's not what you want to pass into the context provider.

Page1 is needs a fix:

```
const [numState, setNumState] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
    setContext(numState);
}, []);
```

Page2 should be:

```
const { setContext } = useContext(SharedContext);

const onClick = () => {
    setContext(1);
    navigate('/page3');
};
```

Page3 should be:

```
const { context } = useContext(SharedContext);

return <div>num = {context}</div>;
```

You are currently doing a pattern that looks like:

```
// The "context" field is the value that you set. It is a number.
const { context } = useContext(SharedContext);
// `num` and `setNum` here are non-sensical
const [num, setNum] = context;
```

Comment: `setContext` expects `[num, setNum]` as an argument, not the page number.